# Updated composer.json, now PHP autoload does not work. PHPUnit cannot find my classes

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, composer-php

I am a user of the [EWZSearchBundle](https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZSearchBundle) and want to update it to work with Symfony 3.x

Updating the `composer.json` file should be easy, but I don't manage to get the unit tests running.

Here is the link to my fork of the bundle with some "improvements": [link to commit](https://github.com/azine/EWZSearchBundle/commit/c48a8b5f2c1ab9ed02ccd92befb8b722c163fb50)

When I run the phpunit tests, I get the following error:

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit Tests/Lucene/FieldTest.php
PHPUnit 5.7.26 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Zend\Search\Lucene\Document\Field::getType() in /tmp/azine/EWZSearchBundle/Tests/Lucene/FieldTest.php on line 18
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/azine/EWZSearchBundle/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /tmp/azine/EWZSearchBundle/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:52
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /tmp/azine/EWZSearchBundle/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:116
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /tmp/azine/EWZSearchBundle/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:186
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /tmp/azine/EWZSearchBundle/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:517
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /tmp/azine/EWZSearchBundle/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:733
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /tmp/azine/EWZSearchBundle/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:868
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() /tmp/azine/EWZSearchBundle/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php:686
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() /tmp/azine/EWZSearchBundle/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:913
PHP  10. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /tmp/azine/EWZSearchBundle/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:1062
PHP  11. EWZ\Bundle\SearchBundle\Tests\Lucene\FieldTest->testGetType() /tmp/azine/EWZSearchBundle/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:1062
```

Steps to reproduce:

```
$ git clone  git@github.com:azine/EWZSearchBundle.git
$ cd EWZSearchBundle
$ composer install
$ vendor/bin/phpunit Tests/Lucene/FieldTest.php
```

The cause of this error is, that the `EWZ\Bundle\SearchBundle\Lucene\Field` class is not (properly) autoloaded, but the `Zend\Search\Lucene\Document\Field` from the `vendor` directory is autoloaded but doesn't have that method.

Can anyone tell me why the autoloading of the classes in the namespace `EWZ\Bundle\SearchBundle` from the root directory does not work?

All help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Share your composer.json, especially the bits related to autoloading

Comment: See https://github.com/azine/EWZSearchBundle/blob/c48a8b5f2c1ab9ed02ccd92befb8b722c163fb50/composer.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class is properly autoloaded. The problem is with the code itself.

When you're initiating a `$binaryField` by code

`$binaryField    = Field::Binary('Binary', 'value');`

the result is of class `\Zend\Search\Lucene\Document\Field`, not of `\EWZ\Bundle\SearchBundle\Lucene\Field`.

Because it executes

 `return new self($name, $value, '', true, false, false, true);`
 inside of `\Zend\Search\Lucene\Document\Field`, and this runs a constructor of `\Zend\Search\Lucene\Document\Field`, not your extended class.

Comment: Thank you so much for finding the error! I was able to fix the problem by implementing the static methods on the `\EWZ\Bundle\SearchBundle\Lucene\Field`.